# Strange sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 MD5 signatures

Tags: ros, rviz, md5, rosmsg, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on some packages using both Electric and Fuerte (alpha). When I try to display the `PointCloud2` output using `rviz` I get messages like this:

```
[ERROR] [1329681881.695481457]: Client [/rviz_1329681880853654796] wants topic /velodyne/pointcloud2 to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/PointCloud/d8e9c3f5afbdd8a130fd1d2763945fca], but our version has [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181]. Dropping connection.
```

On both systems, the correct MD5sum seems to be:

```
$ rosmsg md5 sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181
```

In both cases I am running the Debian binary `rviz` packages, not something I built myself. Any hints where to look for the d8e9c3f5afbdd8a130fd1d2763945fca signature?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27941/strange-sensor_msgs/pointcloud2-md5-signatures/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-02-19**:
Looks like d8e9c3f5afbdd8a130fd1d2763945fca is the default PointCloud (not PointCloud2) message signature (googling for it seems to confirm that at least). Now, why rviz mixes them up of course is the more interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the simple explanation might be that you used a PointCloud display instead of a PointCloud2 display in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-20**:
That was it. The display I had checked was "Point Cloud2 (PointCloud)", but what I intended was "PointCloud2 (PointCloud2)". Sorry for the silly question.